# Selector problem for if/else event listener

Tags: javascript, arrays, selector, event-listener

I'm doing a if/else on a event listener to do +1 or a -1 on a total "likes count" ,  on several elements created by a loop.

The problem is that it doesn't apply to every element even though there's a `foreach`

It works perfectly for the first element, but for the others it only do -1 instead every time.

I know the problem is my selector `const hearts = document.querySelectorAll(".heart");`  called line 93 as `hearts[0]` that only selects the first element with .heart class, but can't figure out how to do it and also select the other ones. Could you guys help me?
I tried using `const hearts = document.getElementsByClassName("heart")[0];` instead but same resumt

If i remove the [0] it throws an error " Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined"

```
//Total likes section
const TotalPhotoLikes= document.querySelectorAll('photoLikes');
const likeInfo= document.getElementById('likeInfo');
const hearts = document.querySelectorAll(".heart");

const allHearts = document.getElementsByClassName("heart")[0];

//Sets initial Total likes 
var sum = 0.0;
$('.photoLikes').each(function() {
  sum += parseFloat(this.value);
} ) ;
likeInfo.textContent= "Total likes:" + sum ;

// Changes total when heart clicked 

hearts.forEach((span) => span.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if( allHearts.classList.contains("liked")){
    $('.photoLikes').each(function() {
      sum = sum + (.35);
    } ) ;
    likeInfo.textContent=  (parseFloat(sum).toFixed(0)) ;
  } 

  else{
    $('.photoLikes').each(function() {
      sum = sum - (.35);
    } ) ;
    likeInfo.textContent=  (parseFloat(sum).toFixed(0)) ;
  }
}))
```

And codepen (line 90 in the JS): https://codepen.io/enukeron/pen/qBaZNbb?editors=1111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your **if** condition is problem in line: 96 (https://codepen.io/enukeron/pen/qBaZNbb?editors=1111)

You should change the if condition to

```
if( span.classList.contains("liked")){
```

ie. span variable contains the selected event

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm supprised i can get the span in the if statement like that. Thought it either needed to be declared beforehand or used in a foreach . Thanks so much !

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks like you are not waiting for all the `li` elements to be appended in by your script. `appenChild` takes a bit of time so wrapping your code in a 100ms setTimeout might fix your issue.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Plus, it manages to pass the -1 part on every li which i guess means the appendChild finishs on time. Thx anyway